# Tinymce adding &nbsp

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, piranha-cms

I am tryng to override the default tinymce in peranhacms like suggested here [Configure / override Piranha CMS html editor so as not to add &nbsp's to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499866/configure-override-piranha-cms-html-editor-so-as-not-to-add-nbsps-to-html)
I spend already about one hour trying to fix that problem. There is a lot of resources on that problem but cant get it work.

- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/correct-way-to-allow-nbsp-entity-in-tinymce
- [tinyMCE adding p tags and nbsp automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079234/tinymce-adding-p-tags-and-nbsp-automatically)
- http://blog.room34.com/archives/5075
- [TinyMCE is adding &nbsp instead of the space when using the word paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247681/tinymce-is-adding-nbsp-instead-of-the-space-when-using-the-word-paste)

Here is how my tinymce.init looks like.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/res.ashx/areas/manager/content/js/ext/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        mode: 'specific_textareas',
        editor_selector: "editor",
        apply_source_formatting: false,
        cleanup_on_startup: false,
        trim_span_elements: false,
        cleanup: false,
        convert_urls: false,
        force_br_newlines: true,
        force_p_newlines: false,
        remove_linebreaks: false,
        convert_newlines_to_brs: false,
        forced_root_block: '',
        inline_styles : true,
        entity_encoding: 'raw',
        verify_html: false,
        //forced_root_block: false,
        validate_children: false,
        remove_redundant_brs: false,
        fix_table_elements: false,

        entities: '160,nbsp,38,amp,60,lt,62,gt',

        plugins: [
            "autoresize autolink code hr paste piranhaimage link"
        ],
        width: "100%",
        height: "340",
        autoresize_min_height: 340,
        @if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/areas/manager/content/css/editor.css"))) {
        <text>content_css: "@Url.Content("~/areas/manager/content/css/editor.css")",</text>
        }
        toolbar: "bold italic underline | bullist numlist hr | formatselect removeformat | cut copy paste | link piranhaimage | code",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: false,
        paste_postprocess: function (pl, o) {
            // remove extra line breaks
            o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/ig, " ");
            alert("a1");
        },
        cleanup_callback: 'my_cleanup_callback',
    });
    function my_cleanup_callback(type, value) {
        alert("a2");
        switch (type) {
            case 'get_from_editor':
                // Remove &nbsp; characters
                value = value.replace(/&nbsp;/ig, ' ');
                alert("a3");
                break;
            case 'insert_to_editor':
            case 'submit_content':
            case 'get_from_editor_dom':
            case 'insert_to_editor_dom':
            case 'setup_content_dom':
            case 'submit_content_dom':
            default:
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }
</script>
```

here is the example of html I use to paste in to tinyice textarea

```
<div class="catelog-box">
    <img src="images/dance.png" alt="dine">
    <div class="cat-detail">
    <h2>Dance</h2>
    <p>Dis purus arcu etiam auctor risus aliquam mid turpis eu vel, nunc rhoncus lacus natoque ridiculus...</p>          
  </div>
</div>
```

And it is how it is looking in browser source:
[image]

I put alerts to check if `paste_postprocess` and `my_cleanup_callback` actually firing, but they are not. And I am still have &nbsp in the html.

I was trying to set `cleanup: true` and `paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true` but it is didnt help to fire `paste_postprocess` and `my_cleanup_callback`

How would you fix the &nbsp problem?

Answer (score 17):

Just adding `entity_encoding: 'raw'` solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The following code clean me everything in the tinymce content

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    invalid_elements :'strong,bold,b,em,br,span,div,p,img,a,table,td,th,tr,header,font,body,h,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5',
    invalid_styles: 'color font-size text-decoration font-weight',
    menubar: false,
    toolbar:false,
    statusbar:false,
    forced_root_block : "",
    cleanup: true,
    remove_linebreaks: true,
    convert_newlines_to_brs: false,
    inline_styles : false,
    entity_encoding: 'raw',
    entities: '160,nbsp,38,amp,60,lt,62,gt',
 });}
```

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE is a monster of options and settings, but given the links you have provided **and** that you've used the clean-up method from [TinyMCE is adding &nbsp instead of the space when using the word paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247681/tinymce-is-adding-nbsp-instead-of-the-space-when-using-the-word-paste), have you tried setting:

```
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true
```

Since this is set in the example you're referencing. Apart from that guess, I have no idea why the event isn't firing.

Best regards

Håkan

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but adding this CSS properties to your editor's element can solve the problem. This is not a tinyMCE issue, this is how the editable divs work.

```css
#editor {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by adding a zero-width-space (`'&#8203;'`) for the defaultContent option.
the TinyMCE code appears to replace empty content with paragraph tags around a non-breaking spaces.

By adding in the zero width space, it appears empty in the UI, but, prevents this post-processing.

For example:

```
let options = { 
   // [...]
   defaultContent: '&#8203;'
   // [...]
}
```